# Can send a Pushnotification without having Backend server in IOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

The application where only four users can share the videos other three users can see the videos and vice versa. I am using cloudkit as a central server.

I would like to send a Push notification without using any Backend server setup to user if one user shared the video.

is there any third party library to obtain this?

Comment: You could if you had proper certificate in the bundle and if your app somehow knew the APNS token of 'the other device'. This last part would be tricky without some kind of server.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry no this is not possible. With Push notifications the Provider needs to send the notification to the APNS (Apple Push Notification Service) which will send it to the correct device.

This works like:

[image]

You are also not able to send files just notifications in the for of Text, sound etc. So no XML file via Push notifications sorry.

You could however do it were you notify the user through Push Notification that there is a file available and then download it when the app opens.

Answer (score 0):

Apple provides [CloudKit](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CloudKitQuickStart/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014987-CH1-SW1) to handle the backend server for you. You can use push notifications though CloudKit by [subscribing to record changes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CloudKitQuickStart/SubscribingtoRecordChanges/SubscribingtoRecordChanges.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014987-CH8-SW4). You can pair devices with [GameKit](https://developer.apple.com/reference/gamekit) for peer to peer connection. Without more information on what you are trying to accomplish this is all the information I can provide.